# YouTube horrible resolution in fullscreen

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, video, resolution, video-playback

I have had this issue with Chrome and YouTube playing videos in a horrible resolution when i switch to fullscreen. My host OS screen resolution is 1920x1080. But flash player often goes down to 640x480 when i switch to fullscreen. When i test this in other browsers (Firefox, IE and Safari): It works all fine.

My specs are:

- **CPU:** Intel Core I7: 950 @ 3.07 GHz
- **Graphics card:** Nvidia GeForce GTX 570 (4048 MB video memory)
- **RAM:** 24 GB (Kingston - Don't remember exact model)
- **Motherboard:** Gigabyte X58A-UD3R
- **OS:** Windows 7 (Version 6.1 - Build 7601)

I run the latest version of Chrome and flash plugin. I have tried re-installing Chrome 2 times already with no luck. I also re-installed my Windows a few weeks ago. I had the same issue before i re-installed.

If there is any more information you need: Be sure to ask and ill provide it right away.

Comment: make sure your google chrome is up-to-date.

Comment: @Sickest Added more details about this above.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess to try, but visit https://www.youtube.com/html5 and request HTML5 player to be used with your browser (just a click of a button), and see if it helps?

Comment: Rather a possibly working workaround than a guess :) I guess that there is a high probability that this would help.

Comment: Does not work. When i use the HTML5 player: It does the same thing. The playback controls are proper sized. But the video canvas is still low resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but it's the first entry on google so I'll tell you my solution to this problem. I already had this happening quite often and it's really annoying.
What worked for me is:

1. right click the video
2. go to settings
3. enable hardware acceleration
4. reload the page.

Many people say to uncheck the hardware acceleration but for me this worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your flash player is up to date. [Link](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/)
2. make sure google chrome is up to date. [Link](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/)
3. right click on the video
4. goto settings.
5. uncheck hardware acceleration, press close.
6. close browser completely, and try watching the video again.

Comment: Triple-checked that i got all the latest versions. I do have all the latest versions of Flash, Chrome and General drivers. I also unchecked hardware acceleration and restarted the OS. Problem is still there...